# Can't uninstall (or update) Internet Explorer 11 Preview Version to Release Version

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, uninstall

OS: Windows 7 32 bit

I don't need to uninstall it completely (and I know it's not possible), I just need to do it, in order to update it to the Release version. Because now, every time I shutdown my computer, Windows tries to update Internet Explorer and 3 minutes later it always fails. I tried to update it manually and it still fails. I tried to uninstall it from

Programs and Features -> Installed Updates -> *Windows Internet Explorer 11*

And it still fails with the following message

> An error has occured. Not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled.

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip it and upload the zip (skydrive, dropbox) and post a link here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today. The user account didn't have administrative privileges on the machine.

Solution: Log on to the machine using an account with administrative rights. Then you'll be able to uninstall (rollback) Internet Explorer via Programs and Features > Installed Updates.

Comment: Sometimes the problems just resolve in their own way. I don't remember how and when it was resolved. But after trying all the solutions in the internet, one day (I guess after some Windows Update) it disappeared. Well if there'll be some problems with Internet Explorer 12, I'll try your method.